# Proving functions to be Big Oh

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms, asymptotics, exponential-function

How do I determine if there exists a function $f$, such that

\begin{equation} 
f(n) = {\mathcal O}(\log n),
\end{equation} but 
\begin{equation} 
2^{f(n)} ≠ {\mathcal O}(n). 
\end{equation}

Is true or false?

I tried using the c and No method but cannot come up with a solution

Comment: What do you mean by "$2f(n)\neq O(n)$ is true or false"?  And do you mean $2^{f(n)}$ (since we were dealing with logs earlier)?

Comment: @tabstop yes I just changed it

Comment: Wouldn't that always be true unless the logarithm were base $2$?

Comment: @recursiverecursion note that $\log_a \in \mathcal O (\log_b)\ \forall\ a,b>0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

Take $f(n)=k\log n=\log n^k$, where $k=\dfrac{2}{\log 2}$. Then clearly, $f(n)={\mathcal O}(\log n)$.

At the same time
$$
2^{f(n)}=2^{\log n^k}=\mathrm{e}^{(k\log 2)\log n}=\mathrm{e}^{2\log n}
=\mathrm{e}^{\log n^2}=n^2,
$$
but the function $2^{f(n)}=n^2$ is definitely not ${\mathcal O}(n)$, as
$$
\frac{2^{f(n)}}{n}\to \infty,
$$
when $n\to\infty$.